# Javaのサーブレットから印刷ダイアログ(printDialog)が表示されない

Tags: tomcat, jsp, java8, servlet

Javaのサーブレット（jspを用いた動的web）から文字列を印刷をしたい場合、以下のようなコードをjavaファイルに記述しますが、

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    PrinterJob pj = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();
    pj.setPrintable(new SomethingPrintable00());
    if (pj.printDialog()) {
        try { pj.print(); }
        catch (PrinterException e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
}
```

開発環境
OS：Windows7 32bit
ツール：Eclipse4.6 NEON
Java8、Tomcat8 モード
では、printDialog メソッドで印刷ダイアログが表示できますが、

実行（エンドユーザー）環境
OS：Windows Server 2012 R2 64bit
Java8 と Tomcat 8.5 をインストール
では、printDialog メソッドを使用しても印刷ダイアログが表示されず、永久ループしてしまいます。
この実行環境で、printDialog メソッドで印刷ダイアログを表示できるようにする方法を教えていただけませんでしょうか？

いずれも、使用ブラウザは Internet Explorer 11 と Google Chrome です。

Comment: OSのWIndows10 64bit PC（PC名をPCA）にて、PCAに開発環境と実行環境を両方入れ、PCAで開発してwarファイルを作り(Eclipseでは印刷ダイアログが表示される)、同じPCAで実行環境モード(Java8、Tomcat8.0)で動かしても、印刷ダイアログが表示されずダメでした。

Comment: 本当に無限ループしているのでしょうか？もしそうであれば、スレッドダンプを短い間隔で複数回取得し、それらを比較してみてください。どこで無限ループしているかが分かります。無限ループの箇所を特定したら、なぜそのループの条件を抜けないのかソースコードを確認してください。